# How to write python-django queries which is ultimately going to call these queries from django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, mongodb-query, django-filter, restframeworkmongoengine

I want to write all types of complex queries, 
for example :

If someone wants information "Fruit" is "Guava" in "Pune District" then  they will get data for guava in pune district.

```
htt//api/?fruit=Guava&?district=Pune
```

If someone wants information "Fruit" is "Guava" in "Girnare Taluka" then  they will get data for guava in  girnare taluka.

```
htt://api/?fruit=Guava&?taluka=Girnare
```

If someone wants information  for "Fruit" is "Guava" and "Banana" then they will get all data only for this two fruits, like wise

```
htt://api/?fruit=Guava&?Banana
```

But, when I run server then I cant get correct output 
If i use `http://api/?fruit=Banana`   then I get all data for fruit which is banana, pomegranate, guava instead of  get data for fruit is only banana. So I am confuse what happen here.
can you please check my code, where I made mistake?
*Here is my all files

models.py

```
class Wbcis(models.Model):

    Fruit = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    District = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    Taluka = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    Revenue_circle = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    Sum_Insured = models.FloatField()

    Area = models.FloatField()

    Farmer = models.IntegerField()                              

def get_wbcis(fruit=None, district=None, talkua=None, revenue_circle=None, sum_insured=None, area=None,min_farmer=None, max_farmer=None, limit=100):

    query = Wbcis.objects.all()

    if fuit is not None:

        query = query.filter(Fruit=fruit)

    if district is not None:

        query = query.filter(District=district)

    if taluka is not None:

        query = query.filter(Taluka=taluka)

    if revenue_circle is not None:

        query = query.filter(Revenue_circle= revenue_circle)

    if sum_insured is not None:

        query = query.filter(Sum_Insured=sum_Insured)

    if area is not None:

        query = query.filter(Area=area)

    if min_farmer is not None:

        query = query.filter(Farmer__gte=min_farmer)

    if max_farmer is not None:

        query = query.filter(Farmer__lt=max_farmer)
    return query[:limit]
```

Views.py

```
class WbcisViewSet(ModelViewSet):

    queryset = Wbcis.objects.all()

    serializer_class = WbcisSerializer


def wbcis_view(request):

    fruit = request.GET.get("fruit")

    district = request.GET.get("district")

    taluka = request.GET.get("taluka")

    revenue_circle = request.GET.get("revenue_circle")

    sum_insured = request.GET.get("sum_insured")

    area = request.GET.get("area")

    min_farmer = request.GET.get("min_farmer")

    max_farmer = request.GET.get("max_farmer")

    wbcis = get_wbcis(fruit, district, taluka,revenue_circle,sum_insured,area, min_farmer, max_farmer)


    #convert them to JSON:

    dicts = []

    for wbci in wbcis:

        dicts.append(model_to_dict(wbci))

    return JsonResponse(dicts)
```

Serializers.py

```
from rest_framework.serializers import ModelSerializer

from WBCIS.models import Wbcis



class WbcisSerializer(ModelSerializer):


    class Meta:

        model = Wbcis

        fields=('id','Fruit','District','Sum_Insured','Area','Farmer','Taluka','Revenue_circle',)
```

whats need changes in this code for call these queries to get exact output?

Comment: I removed code that I didn't believe was relevant to the question (same for the data), if you think anything was removed incorrectly, feel free to roll back and format your question

Comment: yes.  everything is alright now,

Comment: You have a typo in your `get_wbcis` - `if fuit is not None:`

Comment: I see, I change it, but still not get exact information , what we want

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you're actually calling that view, judging by your usage I presume you're calling the viewset itself and then ignoring the query params.

You should follow the [drf docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#filtering-against-query-parameters) for filtering but essentially, provide the get queryset method to your viewset and include the code you currently have in your view in that

```
class WbcisViewSet(ModelViewSet):

    queryset = Wbcis.objects.all()  # Shouldn't need this anymore

    serializer_class = WbcisSerializer


    def get_queryset(self):

        fruit = self.request.query_params.get("fruit")
        ....
        return get_wbscis(...)
```

Comment: okay, so  i need to include this code in views.py file , and delete  def wbcis_view(request):  this code ?

Comment: @KiranPrajapati - I think so, change your `ModelViewSet` to use a `get_queryset` that does what the start of that view did, you also shouldn't need the `queryset` line anymore that I've mentioned here

Comment: Okay, I  all try that you are given link drf docs.  I have one question, if we want to write all types of queries which is ultimately call to django . so rest-framework-filter is only one way ,right?

Comment: @KiranPrajapati - I didn't understand your last comment, if you mean if theres a generic way to write this code then thats the real reason I linked the documentation since there are parts of that that talk about `FilterBackends`... but if you have another question you should really ask it as a new question with what you have tried and researched

Comment: for example:  suppose someone want information :  http://api/?fruit=banana then we not need to write any  other python script  if we  already  use  in views.py file     def get_query(self):    is that correct?

Comment: I still don't understand, the `get_queryset` method should be all you need to write to do that currently.

Comment: okay if we use get_query set, then we don't need to use Q object ?

Comment: @KiranPrajapati - Please try it out first... I don't see where `Q` objects come into it